# Will nesting async functions negatively affect performance?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am working on a form submit and want to get the tokens on submit, because if I get them on page load load they might expire before use.

```
function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    async function getTokens() {
      return axios
        .get("example.com/get-token/306/")
        .then((response) => {
          return response.data;
        });
    }
    getTokens().then((data) => {
      async function submitForm() {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("token", data.message);
        formData.append("session", data.session);
        formData.append("email", email.current.value);

        const res = await axios.post(
          "https://example.com/submit/306/",
          formData,
          {
            headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
          }
        );
      }
      submitForm();
    });
  }
```

Will this significantly decrease performance? The other method I tried is saving the tokens with `setState` on page load, but as I said this risks them expiring before use.

Comment: No it will not decrease performance, however there is no reason for `async/await` in the `submitForm` function, ... you don't actually use `res`.

Comment: Thanks for confirmation. I will be using res for form validation error messages.